# "Keep-Alive" response header for Jetty Web server

Tags: jetty

How to enable "Keep-Alive" response header for Jetty Web server?

Jetty web server - version 7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Connection: Keep-Alive` is only used by HTTP/1.0 clients. The HTTP/1.1 protocol specifies that all connections are persistent by default.

According to the response to [this bug](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JETTY-594) (from 2008), since it claims:

> Jetty uses persistent connections by default for HTTP/1.1 and if requested by the client for HTTP/1.0.

Jetty should respond with a `Connection: Keep-Alive` response header if you connect to it with an HTTP/1.0 client that sends a `Connection: Keep-Alive` request header.